# Orchard cms 1.7.2 GenericADOException

Tags: orchardcms-1.7

Running an orchard site, recently up graded to 1.7.2. seems to work ok for a while then after a few day I get this exception on any of the blog posts pages.

```
 [GenericADOException: could not execute query [ SELECT TOP (@p0) this_.Id as Id332_3_, this_.Number as Number332_3_, this_.Published as Published332_3_, this_.Latest as Latest332_3_, this_.Data as Data332_3_, this_.ContentItemRecord_id as ContentI6_332_3_, autoroutep1_.Id as Id401_0_, autoroutep1_.UseCustomPattern as UseCusto2_401_0_, autoroutep1_.CustomPattern as CustomPa3_401_0_, autoroutep1_.DisplayAlias as DisplayA4_401_0_, autoroutep1_.ContentItemRecord_id as ContentI5_401_0_, contentite4_.Id as Id331_1_, contentite4_.Data as Data331_1_, contentite4_.ContentType_id as ContentT3_331_1_, contenttyp5_.Id as Id333_2_, contenttyp5_.Name as Name333_2_ FROM Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord this_ inner join Orchard_Autoroute_AutoroutePartRecord autoroutep1_ on this_.Id=autoroutep1_.Id left outer join Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord contentite4_ on this_.ContentItemRecord_id=contentite4_.Id left outer join Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord contenttyp5_ on contentite4_.ContentType_id=contenttyp5_.Id WHERE autoroutep1_.DisplayAlias = @p1 and this_.Published = @p2 ] Name:cp0 - Value:news-blog/news Name:cp1 - Value:True [SQL: SELECT TOP (@p0) this_.Id as Id332_3_, this_.Number as Number332_3_, this_.Published as Published332_3_, this_.Latest as Latest332_3_, this_.Data as Data332_3_, this_.ContentItemRecord_id as ContentI6_332_3_, autoroutep1_.Id as Id401_0_, autoroutep1_.UseCustomPattern as UseCusto2_401_0_, autoroutep1_.CustomPattern as CustomPa3_401_0_, autoroutep1_.DisplayAlias as DisplayA4_401_0_, autoroutep1_.ContentItemRecord_id as ContentI5_401_0_, contentite4_.Id as Id331_1_, contentite4_.Data as Data331_1_, contentite4_.ContentType_id as ContentT3_331_1_, contenttyp5_.Id as Id333_2_, contenttyp5_.Name as Name333_2_ FROM Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord this_ inner join Orchard_Autoroute_AutoroutePartRecord autoroutep1_ on this_.Id=autoroutep1_.Id left outer join Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord contentite4_ on this_.ContentItemRecord_id=contentite4_.Id left outer join Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord contenttyp5_ on contentite4_.ContentType_id=contenttyp5_.Id WHERE autoroutep1_.DisplayAlias = @p1 and this_.Published = @p2]]
       at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1573
       at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1472
       at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1467
       at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaLoader.List(ISessionImplementor session) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Criteria\CriteriaLoader.cs:line 76
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl criteria, IList results) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:line 1975
       at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List(IList results) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\CriteriaImpl.cs:line 265
       at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List[T]() in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\CriteriaImpl.cs:line 276
       at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentQuery.Slice(Int32 skip, Int32 count)
       at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentQuery.ContentQuery`1.Orchard.ContentManagement.IContentQuery<T>.Slice(Int32 skip, Int32 count)
       at Orchard.Autoroute.Services.PathResolutionService.GetPath(String path)
       at Orchard.Blogs.Routing.ArchiveConstraint.Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, String parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
       at System.Web.Routing.Route.ProcessConstraint(HttpContextBase httpContext, Object constraint, String parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
       at System.Web.Routing.Route.ProcessConstraints(HttpContextBase httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
       at System.Web.Routing.Route.GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
       at Orchard.Mvc.Routes.ShellRoute.GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
       at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
       at System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.GetVirtualPathForArea(RouteCollection routes, RequestContext requestContext, String name, RouteValueDictionary values, Boolean& usingAreas)
       at System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.GetVirtualPathForArea(RouteCollection routes, RequestContext requestContext, String name, RouteValueDictionary values)
       at System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(String routeName, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, RouteCollection routeCollection, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean includeImplicitMvcValues)
       at System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(String routeName, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
       at System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action(String actionName, String controllerName, Object routeValues)
       at Orchard.Blogs.Extensions.UrlHelperExtensions.BlogArchiveMonth(UrlHelper urlHelper, BlogPart blogPart, Int32 year, Int32 month)
       at ASP._Page_Themes_OrangeCheck_Views_Parts_Blogs_BlogArchives_cshtml.<>c__DisplayClass24.<Execute>b__17(KeyValuePair`2 x) in d:\websites\0d\47324\15961\0x0001\_publishedwebsites\webmatrixwebsite\Themes\OrangeCheck\Views\Parts.Blogs.BlogArchives.cshtml:line 33
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at ASP._Page_Themes_OrangeCheck_Views_Parts_Blogs_BlogArchives_cshtml.Execute() in d:\websites\0d\47324\15961\0x0001\_publishedwebsites\webmatrixwebsite\Themes\OrangeCheck\Views\Parts.Blogs.BlogArchives.cshtml:line 33
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
       at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model)
       at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.Render(ShapeDescriptor shapeDescriptor, DisplayContext displayContext, HarvestShapeInfo harvestShapeInfo, HarvestShapeHit harvestShapeHit)
       at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeTemplateStrategy.ShapeTemplateBindingStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass26.<>c__DisplayClass28.<Discover>b__15(DisplayContext displayContext)
       at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors.ShapeAlterationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass3.<>c__DisplayClass5.<BoundAs>b__2(DisplayContext displayContext)
       at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Process(ShapeBinding shapeBinding, IShape shape, DisplayContext context)
       at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DefaultDisplayManager.Execute(DisplayContext context)
       at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.ShapeExecute(Object shape)
       at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.Invoke(String name, INamedEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Orchard.DisplayManagement.Implementation.DisplayHelper.TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, Object[] args, Object& result)
       at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )
       at Orchard.Core.Shapes.CoreShapes.ContentZone(Object Display, Object Shape, TextWriter Output) in c:\Dev\Orchard\Riders\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Shapes\CoreShapes.cs:line 274
    [InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.]
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
       at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\AdoNet\AbstractBatcher.cs:line 229
       at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1224
       at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 421
       at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 251
       at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1564
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me but on a custom module ive created. 
I re-started the App pool and was gone, although it came back afterwards again. 
After looking around, i saw answers about NHibernate and its mappings file. 
Delete the file and will be re-built, sometimes is gets corrupted.

Comment: This would make sense, there is no Mapping.bin in the deployment files So I'm guessing this gets created on the server, then at some point gets corrupt. Any Ideas how to trace that ?

Comment: ~/App_Data/Sites/*SiteName*/mappings.bin